# Semantic UI remove/modify form validation fields

Tags: forms, validation, semantic-ui

I'm trying to remove or modify form validation after it has been set (In the case of a dynamic form where inputs may get added or removed dynamically.). I cannot figure out how to do this.

Adding in new fields does just that, adds new fields. It doesn't seem to override existing form validation fields.

How can I remove, or change form validation fields in Semantic UI?

Answer (score 2):

Just re-initialize a form after adding a new element. [Look at this topic](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/910)
I mean do - `$('.ui.form').form({fields: validationRules})` after adding a new element. Also you can add new rules in this moment just:

```
var newValidationRules = $.extend(validationRules, additionalValidationRules);
$('.ui.form').form({fields: newValidationRules})
```

You can reset form Validation rules by this: `$('.ui.form').form('destroy')`